# This food makes my throat hurt or hurts?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subject-verb-agreement

I understand that hurt is a verb and when it is used with a noun it will either become hurt/hurts depending on the singularity or plurality of the noun.

However, I saw a native speaker said that the correct form of the sentence is this:
This food makes my throat hurt.

I researched on the web but I couldn't find the answer. Does it have to do with the type of sentence or the type of the word hurt itself in the sentence that makes the throat 'hurt' but not 'hurts'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe "hurt" in that sense is being used as an adjective. Other similar sentences:

- This food makes my belly happy.
- These wheels make my car fast.
- This shampoo makes my hair shiny.